# How to write integers with different sizes to a file

Tags: python

in my code, I write integers and string to the same line of an output text file as follows:

```
f.write("%d\t%d\t%d\t%s"%(int_2b_var, int_4b_var, int_8b_var, string_val))
```

where `int_2b_val` needs to be an integer of 2 bytes, `int_4b_var` an int of 4 bytes and `int_8b_var` an int of 8 bytes.

How can I manage to write the int variables with the desired length into my txt file?

Comment: But `%d` means "decimal number"... Or is that what you're asking about?

Comment: A 2-byte integer could have any where from 1 to 5 digits, being in the range 0 through 65,535. If what you actually want is to write just those 2 bytes, and not a base-10 string representation of the number, you'll probably want the `struct` module.

Comment: 256 and 32768 are both *2 bytes integers*. What do you want in your text file?

Comment: Or is the byte-length of the value irrelevant, and you just want uniformly wide columns regardless of how many digits an individual value in that column requires? Something like `f.write("%5d..." % (...))` may be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

1. you need to write *bytes* (and open the file in binary mode) as here you're going to write a textual representation of the numbers and e.g. the textual representation of 1 byte is up to 4 characters (-128)
2. use the [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) module, which is used to pack data into binary form, see the *format characters* for how to specify the details of your packing e.g. byte order
3. you'll also need to encode `string_val` and decide how you want to reify it exactly e.g. `s` needs a hard-coded number of items (so you might need to encode the string length as well), `p` is limited to 255 bytes, ...

Comment: sorry to bother but I'm not yet very skilled in variables handling. If I got it correctly, I can control the integer length only saving the output file in a binary file. What if I need to save the data in a text file?

Comment: @user123892 then I either misunderstood the question or it makes no sense: you can store a 2-byte integer to text as you did above (by converting it to as string), you can't store it *as 2 bytes* because bytes are not textual content, they're binary data.